# Access remote MySQL (3306) via NodeJS returns No Route (113 MySQL)

Tags: mysql, linux, node.js, debian, iptables

I'm trying to access my VPS's (external) MySQL database over default protocol using NodeJS's MySQL connection. After a lot of debugging I found out, by even trying it on the virtual machine using the default mysql -h -u -p handle that I'm getting the 113 response, which would mean that I cannot access it from remote hosts (for the VPS's point of view).

Strangely enough I got it working via XAMPP a month or 2 ago and now I can't access it for some reason. I've tried the iptables (I'm not insanely adept with Linux), tried telnetting but no responses.

On my VPS, `netstat -an | grep 3306` returns:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN`

I'm at a terrible loss on what to do... Anybody else got some brilliant insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, another firewall was actively blocking my requests as there were 2 rules. My lack of Linux knowledge kept me from seeing it. The first result in the IPTABLES is leading and that one was blocking my requests.